# how to print an array of objects in codeigniter- php?

Tags: codeigniter

I am facing a problem to fetch array in codeigniter

```
$data['one']=$this->db->query($sql1);
$data['tho']=$this->db->query($sql2);
$data['three']=$this->db->query($sql3);
```

I am trying to do this following code I am getting error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in
```

If I do `var_dump($data['one']);` I am getting the following displayed:

```
Array
(
 [0] => stdClass Object
 (
  [date] => 2013-09-28
 )
 [1] => stdClass Object
 (
  [date] => 1970-01-01
 )
 [2] => stdClass Object
 (
  [date] => 2013-09-28
 ) 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do (in the controller) something like this foreach one of your arrays:

```
  foreach ($data['one']->result() as $row)
  {
        echo $row->date; //or whatever the query returns
  }
```

If you want to print it on the view you do it like this:

```
  foreach ($one->result() as $row)
  {
        echo $row->date; //or whatever the query returns
  }
```

See more in the official documentation about queries [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/examples.html)